# Many to many relations LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, php-7, laravel-6

I have a problem retrieving data from a third table, as you can see I have three tables:

1. Models : id , code , title
2. levels : id , code . title
3. models_level : model_id,level_id

I have as function :

```
 $model = model::paginate(10);
    $level = level::all();
    $models_level = models_level::all();
    return view('pg',compact('model','level','models_level'));
```

How can I retrieve the level name based on the model id retrieved?

Here is my blade

```
 <tbody>
            @foreach($model as $f)
                <tr class="item{{$f->id}}">
                    <td style="font-size: 13px;"> {{$f->title}}</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 13px;">{{$f->code}}</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 13px;">{{$f->models_level->level_id}}</td> 
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            {{ $filiere->links() }}

            </tbody>
```

I need to show the title in level instead of the ID.

> in this case I have 2 different tables and the 3 rd is associative
>   table that contains the two , so I have to pass by model to get
>   model_level . get the level id depending on the model_id and the go to
>   level and find the title ..

Comment: use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

```
Models
– id

levels
– id

models_level
– product_id
– shop_id
```

here **models_level** table is called as pivot table
app/Model.php

```
class Model extends Model
{

    public function levels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\level','models_level');
    }
}
```

app/level.php

```php
class Level extends Model
{

    public function Models()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shop','models_level');
    }
}
```

---

```php
$model = model::with('levels')->paginate(10);
return view('pg',compact('model'));
```

```php
<tbody>
            @foreach($model as $f)
                <tr class="item{{$f->id}}">
                    <td style="font-size: 13px;"> {{$f->title}}</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 13px;">{{$f->code}}</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 13px;">{{$f->levels[0]->id}}</td> 
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            {{ $filiere->links() }}

            </tbody>
```

You can read more about [many to many relationships in the docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: thank you for your efforts, in my model for model I have it like this public function levels()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\level::class)
     ->withPivot('mode_formation_id');
 }

Comment: @MnlLBD yes it is pivot table

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using a One to Many relationship and you have the correct methods in you model classes.

This way you can change your controller method to:

```
$model = model::with('level')->paginate(10);
return view('pq', $model);
```

and in your blade files loop:

```
<td style="font-size: 13px;">{{$f->level->title}}</td>
```

You should read up on eloquent relationships in the laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: i have tried this but it gives me an error, they are 3 tables and the model_level is an association table